# How to fix an element that is inline with another element regardless of previous element's size

Tags: html, css

I have four `div`s that are all `inline`. However, I need to have the distance between the first and the second `div` stay the same, regardless of how long the first `div` is. Here is a picture:

[image: Code picture]

As you can see, on the second line, the 'Save for later' (and the rest of the `div`s) are moved a bit because Name - Joe takes up more space than Name - Bob. How can I have these stay the same regardless of the previous `div` length? I am trying to figure out a way without having to do it individually.

Here's my code:

```css
.searchProgramsResult {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  background-color: #DADBDB;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 10px;
  margin-top: 25px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #2BC2D3;
  font-weight: 500;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional1 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 300px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #47BC47;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsBar {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 500px;
  font-size: 38px;
  color: #0F0F0F;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
.searchProgramsAdditional2 {
  font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  padding-left: 550px;
  font-size: 28px;
  color: #D41B1B;
  font-weight: 500;
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<div class = "searchProgramsResult" id = "searchProgramsResult1">Name - Bill<span class = "searchProgramsAdditional1" id = "searchProgramsAdditional11">Save for later</span><span class = "searchProgramsBar"> - </span><span class = "searchProgramsAdditional2" id = "searchProgramsAdditional12">Report a bug</span></div>
<div class = "searchProgramsResult" id = "searchProgramsResult2">Name - Joe<span class = "searchProgramsAdditional1" id = "searchProgramsAdditional21">Save for later</span><span class = "searchProgramsBar"> - </span><span class = "searchProgramsAdditional2" id = "searchProgramsAdditional22">Report a bug</span></div>
```

You will want to open this code snippet as a full page because this code was built for a website.

Comment: you can make your second DIV `position:relative` and give it a fix position from one side, like `left:100px`

Comment: This didn't work for me.

Comment: Add `.searchProgramsResult { display: flex; }`

Comment: Instead of using right padding to create the space, put "Name-Bill" in its own `<span>` and give it a width.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the names in `span` elements as well then use CSS tables.

```css
div {
  display: table-row;
}

span {
  display: table-cell;
  padding: 0 1em;
}

.name {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

```html
<div class="searchProgramsResult" id="searchProgramsResult1"><span class="name">Name - Bill</span><span class="searchProgramsAdditional1" id="searchProgramsAdditional11">Save for later</span><span class="searchProgramsBar"> - </span><span class="searchProgramsAdditional2" id="searchProgramsAdditional12">Report a bug</span></div>
<div class="searchProgramsResult" id="searchProgramsResult2"><span class="name">Name - Joe</span><span class="searchProgramsAdditional1" id="searchProgramsAdditional21">Save for later</span><span class="searchProgramsBar"> - </span><span class="searchProgramsAdditional2" id="searchProgramsAdditional22">Report a bug</span></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what exactly you want to achieve. From what you have posted I personally would not use `div`s but a `table` (or `div`s with `display:table` and so on). Here's a very short snippet to get an idea how to achieve what you want with `div`s.

```css
#div1, #div2 { 
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1% 0%;
  background: red;
}
.col1, .col2, .col3 { display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; }
.col1 { padding: 1%; width: 48%; background: green; }
.col2 { padding: 1%; width: 22%; background: yellow; }
.col3 { padding: 1%; width: 22%; background: blue; }
```

```html
<div id="div1">
  <div class="col1">Some text...</div>
  <div class="col2">Button1</div>
  <div class="col3">Button2</div>
</div>

<div id="div2">
  <div class="col1">Some longer text...</div>
  <div class="col2">Button1</div>
  <div class="col3">Button2</div>
</div>
```